# spring data neo4j 6 @Query @Param can't access 2nd level children

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I've a single object in the @Param to be used in @Query whereas the 1st level fields can be accessed without issues, but not the 2nd level. Unable to access fields from **Language** object

Consider:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "description": "some text",
  "language": {
    "name": "English"
  }
}

@RelationshipProperties
@Data
public class KnowsEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue()
  private Long id;

  @Property
  private String description;

  @TargetNode
  private Language language;
}

@Query("MATCH (y:PERSON {nid: $from})-[r:KNOWS]->(e:LANGUAGE {name: $rel.__language__.__name__ }) \n" +
        "WHERE ID(r) = $rel. id  SET r.description = $rel.__description__  \n" +
        "return y, collect(r), collect(e)")
UpdatedLanguageProjection updateRel(@Param("from") String from, @Param("rel") KnowsEntity relation);
```

form the above query i could access the first level field `$rel.__description__` and not the field inside first level object `$rel.__language__.__name__` (2nd level)

can someone please correct / suggest me an option to get this?

Answer (score 0):

I got this worked with the following SpEL way

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/6.1.1/reference/html/#custom-queries.spel

eg: `{name: :#{#rel.language.name}}`